# Why is $b "b" in this logic when echoing out ${$b}

Tags: php, variables

I'd have expected ${$b} to be 'a' but it is 'b', why is this the case?

```
$a = "b";
$b = "a";
```

Sorry again I forgot to put ${$b} produces "b"

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code.

Comment: You might want to include some code...

Comment: the code where you access the value of $b is probably suspect... check that or post it.

Comment: Ha ha, my silly fault for forgetting the second bit.

Comment: You get "b" when you do print $$b

Comment: Stay away from symbolic references, especially if you don't really know what you're doing. And clearly, you don't. See this classic post: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html for why -- it is written for Perl, but it applies to PHP too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [variable variable expression](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) `${$b}` takes the value of `$b` for the variable name. So `${$b}` evaluates to `${"a"}` that is equivalent to `$a` that then evaluates to `"b"`.

Answer (score 3):

> If you use the ${$b} it is equal to
>   $a. So that time it will print "b" 
>   only.

Answer (score 2):

It couldn't be.

```
$b = "a";
${$b} == $a;
$a = "b";
${$b} == "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of is that when you're getting its value you forgot the `$`.  This is a pretty common typo for new php programmers (and even for experienced ones that program in other languages).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense now with your addition

```
Sorry again I forgot to put ${$b} produces "b"
```

that works as intended: You are using `$b` (containing "a") as a variable name. So as the end result, you are querying `$a`.